# sfdisk --no-read doesn't work

Tags: debian, sfdisk

I am trying to extend a partition using sfdisk on debian 8. I am running the following command:

```
    sfdisk -H 255 -S 63 --quiet --Linux --leave-last -uM --force --no-reread /dev/md1 -N4 < /tmp/abc
```

I am getting the following error when I ran the command:

```
    Successfully wrote the new partition table
    Re-reading the partition table ...
    sfdisk: BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
    sfdisk: The command to re-read the partition table failed.
    Run partprobe(8), kpartx(8) or reboot your system now,before using mkfs
    sfdisk: If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1) to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1 (See fdisk(8).)
```

Why does the re-read happen when I have mentioned `--no-reread`? 
I am running this on `sfdisk` from util-linux 2.25.2. When I run the same command on `sfdisk` from sfdisk (util-linux-ng 2.17.2), I do not experience this error. Is there any difference between the two which is causing this error to occur?

Answer (score 5):

The `--no-reread` option tells `sfdisk` to not check for if the device is in use (e.g. mounted or swap).

The error you are getting is from the `sfdisk` telling the *kernel* that the partition information has changed; the kernel is responding "hey, this device is already in use; I'm not going to read the new partition data".

So now the kernel copy of the partition data is different to the actual data on the disk.

Without the `--no-reread` then `sfdisk` wouldn't let you do the partitioning at all.

Comment: How do I get the kernel to update the partition table then?

Comment: `sfdisk` tells you; `partprobe`, `kpartx` or a reboot.  If the disk is in use (eg it's your root disk sharing with other partitions) it may be a reboot is the only way.  It's what I'd do, to be safe :-)

Comment: Is there a reason why I see this error when I am running sfdisk from util-linux 2.25.2 and not when I am running sfdisk (util-linux-ng 2.17.2). Thanks in advance.